# issue while updating value in sqlite table with update query

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I'm implementing **sqlite** in my **swift project** and with **update** `query` i am **updating** some `value` from `table` but i am getting **syntax error** i am not sure why i am getting **error**.

**UPDATE Code**

```
 let updateStatementString = "UPDATE CreateInspDrawingDetail SET edit_file_name = \(self.imgbase64!) WHERE property_id = \(property_ID!) AND properties_drawings_id = \(self.drawingID!)"
 var updateStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
 if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, updateStatementString, -1, &updateStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(updateStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
               print("Successfully updated row.")
        } else {
               print("Could not update row.")
        }
      } else {
            print("UPDATE statement could not be prepared")
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(updateStatement)
```

i am getting **syntax error** like below

> near "/": syntax error UPDATE statement could not be prepared

i am do anything wrong in my query please tell me

Comment: Don't assign updateStatement as nil. var updateStatement : OpaquePointer?

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: Still i am getting syntax error after i remove nil

Comment: Try to change SQLITE_DONE to SQLITE_OK. In the first if condition with nil for updateStatement.

Comment: Okay i am trying but can you please tell me query syntax is right?

Comment: i tried with SQLITE_OK but still same error

Comment: Have you tried to print the statement before preparing it to see if it looks ok with the property values inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
let updateStatementString = "UPDATE CreateInspDrawingDetail SET edit_file_name = '\(self.imgbase64!)' WHERE property_id = '\(property_ID!)' AND properties_drawings_id = '\(self.drawingID!)';"
 var updateStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
 if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, updateStatementString, -1, &updateStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(updateStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
               print("Successfully updated row.")
        } else {
               print("Could not update row.")
        }
      } else {
            print("UPDATE statement could not be prepared")
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(updateStatement)
```

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: WelCome Happy Coding :)